# How to move between words in a function name in Visual Studio Express? Ex : public void moveCursonBetweenTheseCapitalizedWords() { }

Tags: .net, visual-studio, editor

Like in Eclipse, when we say Ctrl + Left/Right arrow, the cursor moves between the words in a method when they are capitalized. I would like to do the same in visual studio express. Is it possible?

currently when I say Ctrl + Left/Right, the cursor moves to the end considering the whole function name as a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excellent [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) add-in for VS has this feature and calls it CamelHumps. I don't believe it's available in plain Visual Studio.

*edit* As noted by Simeon Pilgrim below, question reading failure on my part, sorry- Express doesn't support add-ins :(

Comment: But as he's running Express, as noted by John, he can't use plug-ins/add-ins.

Comment: Yea, I came across the CodeRush Express (which is free) but I cannot plug into my express VS.. :( Thanks